# saving the string contained in a file, in an array of strings and i don't the best format for the array

Tags: arrays, c

the code should read a file of this type, containing a series of rock, paper scizor matches, through the read_file function and then return the array containing all the information in the file

paper rock

scizor rock

rock scizor

paper scizor

scizor rock

rock scizor

i don't know how should actually be defined a proper array for this task and how i should sscanf into it

i need then to pass all the words in the file to a function and then convert the strings to number,
example
rock should turn into 1
(this is to make comparison between them easier later on)

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHAR_MOVE 8

#define rock 1
#define paper 2
#define scizor 3






int figure_code(char *name)
{
    if (strcmp(name, "rock") == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(name, "paper") == 0)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if (strcmp(name, "scizor") == 0)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        return -1;
}



char *Read_File(FILE *infile, int *n)
{
    int i;
    int dim = 4;
    char buf[1000];
    char p[dim][MAX_CHAR_MOVE];
    char *list;
    list  = &p[0][0];







    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf), infile) != NULL )
    {
        sscanf(buf, "%s %s", *(list[*n]), *(list[*n+1]));
        *n = *n+2;
        if (*n>= dim)
            {
            dim = dim*2;
            list = realloc (list,  sizeof(*list) * dim);
            }

     }


        return list;
}



void print_everything(char *list, int n)
{
    int c;
    int z;
    for (c = 0;c<n; c++ ){
        printf("%s\n", list[c]);
    }
}





int main(int argc,const char *argv[])
{
FILE *f;
char *list[][];
int n;

if (!( argc != 3)){
    printf("wrong dimension\n");
    return -1;
}

f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

list = Read_File(f, &n);

print_everything(elenco, n);
fclose(f);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to convert the data to integers: `int data[n][2];` and then `data[0][0] = 1; /*paper*/ data[0][1] = 0; /*rock*/ data[1][0] = 2; /*scizor*/` ... maybe use an enum? `enum choice { ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS };`

Comment: you probably mean "scissors"

Comment: `char *list; sscanf(buf, "%s %s", *(list[*n]), *(list[*n+1]));` For starters you need to allocate memory and assign it to `list`. You can't write to an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: the file should contain random sequences of rock paper, scissors

Comment: i can't allocate the memory if don't know the dimension of the array. array that would allow me to convert each word into a number through the function

Comment: `list  = &p[0][0];` followed by `realloc(list` is wrong - you cannot realloc with a pointer to an array. You can realloc with a pointer to dynamic allocated memory.

Comment: ok, so how do i define a pointer, poiting to a matrix[dinamyc_dimension][fixed_dimension]

Comment: warning: incompatible pointer types returning 'char (*)[8]' from
      a function with result type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                return list;
                       ^~~~    at this point how do i define the function to return a list of that type?

Comment: lastly i don't   know hot to sscanf in this type of array string after string, 2 strings each line

Comment: sscanf(buf, "%s %s", list[*n], list[*n+1]);
  printf("%s\n", (*list)[*n]);
  printf("%s\n", (*list)[*n+1]);   like this i  get this worning morra.c:49:18: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'char' [-Wformat]
                printf("%s\n", (*list)[*n]);
                        ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~
                        %c
morra.c:50:18: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'char' [-Wformat]
                printf("%s\n", (*list)[*n+1]);
                        ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        %c

Comment: perfect, it works just fine now